# Calculate the fundamental group of $S^1/\mathbb Z_n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Calculate the fundamental group of $S^1/\mathbb Z_n$
,where $\mathbb Z_n$ acts naturally on $S^1$ by rotations of $2\pi /n$

The origin of this problem is the following unclear solution of another problem:

[image]

I restate the question in picture here:

> **PROBLEM**  Compute $\pi_1 (X)$, where $X$ is the quotient space of a torus   $S^1\times S^1$
>    obtained by identifying points on the circle  $S^1 \times\{y_0\}$
>    that differ by rotations of the circle by  $\frac{2\pi}{n}$
>   for $y_0$ a base point in the second $S^1$ factor and $n\ge2$ a fixed
>   integer

My question is how to give a rigor and systematical answer, not just some intuitive or geometrical answers. 
What puzzled me is that in the above picture, it claims that the fundamental group of $S^1/\mathbb Z_n$ is $\mathbb Z_n$ . However, I guess $S^1/\mathbb Z_n$ seems to be homeomorphic to $S^1$; hence, the fundamental group should be $\mathbb Z$.

I think here we cannot use Van-Kampen theorem and we must back to the definition.
Please help!

Comment: Isn't $S^1/\mathbb Z_n\cong S^1$ anyway?

Comment: I do think so.Please see my edit.

Comment: I point out that Chapter 11 of the book "Topology and Groupoids" (available from amazon) determines the fundamental groupoid of an orbit space under a properly discontinuous action, e.g. that of a finite group on a Hausdorff space. An older version of this chapter is available at arXiv:math/0212271. I can't work out more now as I am travelling tomorrow!

Comment: Where is this text excerpt from? The claim that *"Since the homotopy class of $a$ serves as the sole generator and identity of $\pi_1(S^1,x_0)$, ..."* is just stupid. The identity of a group is never a generator for anything except the trivial group. The identity of $\mathbb{Z}$ is $e=0$, the generator of $\mathbb{Z}$ (up to sign) is $1$. Believe it or not, $1\neq 0$. *"...this implies that $q_*([a]^n)=e$ in $\pi_1(S^1/\mathbb{Z}^n)$"* is then also patently false.

Comment: What the author has instead shown is that $q_*([a])=[a]^n$ (obviously this only makes sense after one identifies $\pi_1(S^1)$ with $\pi_1(S^1/\mathbb{Z}_n)$ via an isomorphism). Not to mention that $\mathbb{Z}^n$ should be $\mathbb{Z}_n$, unless there is some important context missing. There are several other typos, such as claiming $q_*\colon S^1\to S^1/\mathbb{Z}^n$ when really this should be $q$, and claiming that a map $S^1\vee S^1\twoheadrightarrow S^1$ somehow induces a map on fundamental groups **in the other direction?**

Comment: By Van Kampen's Theorem (puncture a point on the interior of the $2$-cell), shouldn't we get $\pi_1(X) \cong \langle x,y, \mid x^nyx^{-n}y^{-1} = e \rangle$ which I don't believe has torsion.